# Wolfram Mathematica: Why not looking for a maximum in real numbers?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

```
Maximize[{Log[B e^(20 a)] - (B (-1 + e^(20 a)))/(a Log[e]), a > 0, 
  B > 0, e > 1}, {a, B, e}, Reals]
```

Comment: There is a stack exchange site dedicated to Mathematica: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com, you may want to ask there if you don't get a reply here.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably no closed-form solution for that transcendental equation.

```
NMaximize[{Log[B e^(20 a)] - (B (-1 + e^(20 a)))/(a Log[e]), a > 0, 
  B > 0, e > 1}, {a, B, e}, Reals]
```

Gives

> {-1.55421, {a -> 1.14072, B -> 3.85825*10^-6, e -> 1.67175}}

and the message

> The function value Indeterminate is not a number at {a,B,e} = 
>   {1.153668136677547,0.,1.688137312684115}